# ¿Cómo puedo mandar a renderizar un componente desde otro al presionar un botón en react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Necesito renderizar un componente llamándolo desde otro, al presionar un botón. A su vez cuando llamo al componente le quiero enviar una propiedad y poder recibirla en el otro componente. Estoy en el componente funcional Home y quiero renderizar el componente funcional Editproduct.

```
    import Editproduct from '../adminstock/Editproduct';

    const Home = (props) =>{

      function editTarget(event, index){

         event.preventDefault();
         console.log(products[index]);

         return(<Editproduct productArray={products}/>);
      }

    return(
       <div>
          <Button 
              onClick={(event) => editTarget(event, index)}
              entry = {index}>
              <Edit color="primary" fontSize="small"/>
          </Button>
       </div>
    );
   }
```

En el botón que creé estoy llamando a la función editTarget y en esa función necesito retornar el componente nuevo y que se visualice su render.

Comment: Creo que hace falta más código para visualizar exactamente que quieres hacer, una imagen guía también sería útil. ¿En dónde vas a inyectar ese <Editproduct/>?

Comment: Si quieres renderizar el componente <Editproduct/> en Home, sería mejor que fuera una etiqueta condicionada por la acción del botón.

Comment: Como hago esa etiqueta condicionada por la accion del boton? @Parzival

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo exactamente que es lo que deseas hacer, pero esto debería renderizar un `<Editproduct/>` al presionar el botón.

```
//Importa useState
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Editproduct from '../adminstock/Editproduct';

    const Home = (props) =>{

    //Utiliza el hook useState
    const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

    handleButtonClick = () => {
        setButtonClicked(true)
    }

    return(
       <div>
          <Button 
              onClick={() => handleButtonClick}
              entry = {index}>
              <Edit color="primary" fontSize="small"/>
          </Button>

          //Utiliza una condición ternaria para condicionar el render de la etiqueta.
          //Si se presionó el botón buttonClicked === true y se renderiza. 
          //En caso contrario devuelve null y no renderiza nada.
          {buttonClicked ? <Editproduct productArray={products}> : null}
       </div>
    );
   }
```

Si no hace nada, prueba cambiar esto:

```
onClick={() => handleButtonClick}
```

por:

```
onClick={handleButtonClick}
```

Comment: No era lo que queria exactamente, pero me sirvio mucho! Gracias